# Creating certificates gives different name for development and distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone-developer-program

My mac was registered in the past as a developer with individual program.

Now, we are registered as a company, so i have downloaded Xcode with the company Apple ID.

I have created a certificate file (`csr`) using keychain->`request a certificate from authority..`.

Than on the portal, when i am uploading this csr to create a `distribution` certificate, it works great and creates the file under the **company name**.(the certificate name appears at the end as company name.)

When than trying to create a certificate for development(with this *same* `csr` file ), i get a development certificate **under my personal name**, and *not* the company name as before.

Why is that happens? i am using the same csr, and i don't see the company name under the development certificate, but my personal name instead .

(the previous developer account on this mac was under my name )

Comment: oh maybe is that the way it should be ? so that the company name is the distribution file, but any other development certificate is the developer name? if it is, how apple extract my name to the file? from the mac name?